# What is the meaning of Murray words in his conditions?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Adventure movie *The Lost City of Z (2016)*, Murray volunteered to join Percy Fawcett's Geographic mission.

Murray was unable to survive due to lot of adventures and then gave up his journey for returning to home.

So Murray complained to RGS trustees about Fawcett carelessness about him on the expedition and also he gave chance to Fawcett to withdrew his complaints on him with some conditions, This conditions made Fawcett angry and resigned from the present institution.

> Fawcett: I will, of course, need to hear Mr. Murray's conditions.
>
> Murray: On the day that I agreed to join you on your mission and
>   **allowed your star to enter my sphere**, your wife was present to witness
>   your ascent. My only condition is that she again be present to witness
>   your acknowledgement of the wrongs that you have done to me.

What is the meaning of **allowed your star to enter my sphere** in his conditions ?

Comment: This is a reference to the language of [Hamlet](http://m.sparknotes.com/nfs/hamlet/page_258.html) and other archaic understandings of astronomy, in which the stars were said to move in their "spheres". The expression means to stay in your proper area, your social class, your own nature, etc. Murray means that he made an exception and allowed Fawcett into his own sphere. Although the full expression is somewhat dated now, people still describe things as being "out of their sphere of expertise" (beyond them).

Comment: @LukeSawczak: Seems like that should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of "stars moving in their spheres" is an allusion to an older set of terms used in astronomy. Today, you could understand it more or less as "objects in space moving in their orbits".

This idea, that celestial bodies are limited to their orbit and can never leave, was also tied with ideas present at the time about *social order* and proper hierarchy. A person is born into their particular "sphere", and only moves within it. To move outside it would be contrary to nature.

This idea then moved into poetry, for example in [Hamlet, Act 4, scene 7](http://m.sparknotes.com/nfs/hamlet/page_258.html):

> She's so conjunctive to my life and soul
>   
>  that, as the star moves not but in his sphere,
>   
>  I could not but by her.
>
> (*She's so intertwined with my life that, like a planet stuck in its orbit, I must move alongside her.)*

It was also possible to shorten the expression to "one's sphere".

> Why can't I marry her? Because I'm not in her sphere. *(I'm not worthy of her class of people.)*

In your quote, Murray is telling Fawcett that he made an exception to the way things ought to be — he "allowed Fawcett's star to enter his own sphere", and Fawcett should appreciate it.

Although this poetic expression has more or less disappeared from modern life along with the astronomical and social worlds it described, we still use "sphere" sometimes to mean "area".

> Sorry, I can't do anything about your promotion. That's not in my **sphere of influence**.
>
> The professor was asked to consult on the porject, but it was not his **sphere of expertise**.